# Enable Emmet (Zen Coding) for SASS files in Phpstorm?

Tags: css, sass, phpstorm, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

How can I enable Emmet coding for `CSS` on my `SASS` files without adding all of the rules manually?

Example, in type in `db` and hit tab it will auto complete to `display: block;`

[image]

Comment: You have highlighted the area on your screenshot where user can change the context where specific Live Template can be sued. But .. does SASS is actually listed there? If not .. then why did you post this screenhot?

Comment: Not sure I follow @LazyOne As you can see in the screenshot, I could add `sass` to the defines, which would mean that the `Zen CSS` would become avalible for `sass`. I want to enable all of the rules found in `Zen Coding` for `sass` without doing them manually.

Comment: *"Not sure I follow @LazyOne As you can see in the screenshot, I could add sass to the defines"* -- where? Please show me this on screenshot (this or another; where I can **clearly** see "SASS" option).

Comment: Thing is: CSS live templates work fine in CSS, SASS/SCSS and LESS for sure -- tested (and using) myself in v8 at least (I'm using just a few of them .. but they do work for me).

Comment: Thanks Lazy, it must be some other settings. I'll see what I can do to get it back to the default behaviour.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Make sure to enable `fuzzy search among CSS abbreviations` in Settings/Emmet - does it help?

Comment: Bingo baby! Without it I would get this when typing `db` `dominant-baseline: ;` Thanks

Comment: You're my hero !